# What happens when dotnet build is called with a build configuration that doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, build, dotnet-cli

I did some quick searching and was not able to find an answer to what happens when you do something like

`dotnet build --configuration foobar`

and the configuration `foobar` is not defined. I also tested this out but wasn't able to tell what exactly was happening. Does anyone know if it just uses the default configuration i.e. `debug` or `release`?

Comment: The default for most projects is Debug. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build

Comment: When you tried it, did it build? If so, did that not answer your question - a default configuration was used? What is the value/point of this question?

Comment: `dotnet` doesn't seem to tell you what build config it's using, that's the problem.  You can't tell what it's defaulted to.